# Exporting table from a database into a csv file

Tags: database, csv, firefox, export

Good Morning,

I want to export a table, which fetches it's data from a sql database, into a csv file. My problem is that I don't have direct access to that original database, the only possible way to see the data is to log on onto the front end. But, for further procedure, we would like to have the data in a csv file on our computers.

I know it's a bit awkward, but is there a reasonable way to catch the data and export it? What's the best way to do it?

Best regards
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-format retrieved data into JSON object format and use library such below one :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv